If someone is deliberately trying to provoke close votes
... Does that call for moderator action?
I have no objection to Socratic questions. Asking questions intended to teach people to close questions does not strike me as participating in good faith.
(I may have misread the statement which provoked this question. Unfortunately, I am now having trouble finding the exact quote in which the individual appeared to be asking why their question had not been closed. It is quite possible that the tag filters I have switched on are hiding it from me, but since I can't point to the specific instance and the error is quite possibly mine, I should probably withdraw this question. Since there are useful Answers here I can't delete it, but I can take the name of it and apologize if I misread or misunderstood. I probably shouldn't have cited an individual in the first place; that's a demerit to me.)

On a properly run site it probably would. But you may be finding yourself in a place where the officials who nominally are charged with dealing with bad-faith participants have no interest in doing so. If that's the case, you'll have to ask yourself what you could/should do (that's within your powers) to keep this place generally free of bad-faith participants.

On StackExchange, moderators are failsaves, not babysitters. Notably, we are not "officials". We are community members doing this for free. The idea is that community votes deal with 90+% of the problems. At the moment, it looks like we're flooded with flags for every brain fart of any given individual. This makes managing the workload pretty hard.

Understood. I am used to stacks (and discussions elsewhere) where the moderators are a bit more activist in trying to correct deliberate/repeat offenders. If you view this as beyond your acceptable workload, I can understand that. And yes, excessive use of flags is its own problem, as is overuse of close votes when down voting would be more appropriate. Personally, I'm not convinced that letting somebody deliberately make the situation worse to make it visible actually will make it better, but it's your call.

Honestly, it feels as if there is a hostile takeover underway to control the content on this site. You have a few users that are asking the same types of questions on a daily basis and complain loudly when anyone downvotes or votes to close. What are the moderators to do? All it takes is a coalition of 5 users to close/reopen questions and effectively control content on the entire site.

@IdiosyncraticSoul - Heck, one of the moderators is openly trying to organize such a coalition, "I think we should just gather some people willing to reopen these questions".

What is the context, can you link to where Miss_Understands said this?

... Actually, I may have misinterpreted what was said. I withdraw the question, with apologies.

I can't delete the question since there were useful answers to it, but I can take the individual's name off it and apologize if I misread / misunderstood. Which, given that we were getting frustrated with each other, is not unlikely. Heat drives out light.

@causative Closest I can find: "You will vote to close this because..." and "people will forcibly misinterpret this question as hostile because 1) They have an excuse to get mad and ignore the question..." (and "do admins close the questions they dislike", but someone else edited that in). It's debatable whether that's "deliberately trying to provoke close votes". But it's certainly antagonistic and that doesn't belong in a question (and indeed those were edited out).

@keshlam Divorce questions? As usual, I'm lost in context —  bewildered, wandering around aimlessly like a lost child, looking for something that only existed a long time ago, but turns out, it never really was.

You won't be "hated"  if we better understand where you're coming from. And that isn't special accommodation, it's something we should be trying to extend to everyone. (FWIW, my reaction was confusion rather than hatred.)And in fact I do believe folks are entitled to whatever pronoun they want, though a bit of slack is appropriate when others do try but get it wrong. "Absolute is the right if any man to spell his name Jones and have it pronounced Smith."

Divorce was an autodefect typo; let me fix that:
I have confirmed that I did misread "And yet you answered it [despite thinking it might be better closed] ... LEARN, people!" as advocating for ignoring/closing offtopic questions rather than for closing fewer questions. (I can type well enough on a real keyboard that I've gotten out of the habit of proofreading before hitting send. I'm still learning that I can not get away with that on phone or tablet.)

Right of any man; inadvertent illustration of my failure to consistently proofread. I'm trying. (And the Greek chorus says, in unison,  "yes, very!")

@keshlam I use voice typing, and the AI will not generate syntactically incorrect statements. I end up writing stuff very different from what I said, often ridiculous. That's why I learned to always spell check my stuff!

@keshlam > Divorce was an autodefect typo; == I'm hoping you meant autocorrect typo, but the auto correct turned it into autodefect because it didn't want to be criticized.

No, that one was a deliberate neologism. My sense of humor leans towards the sardonic. It often is less than successful on line unless I make it very explicit. I seem to keep trying anyway. Sigh.

Keep calm, don't get dragged down, ignore what you can, don't engage to reward attention seeking. Don't respond to provocation, consider always that you are speaking to the future readers, not the asker.
Vote to close with least questionable votes like duplicate.

And, reminding myself, use tag filtering to help avoid being drawn into those discussions. I would consider using author filtering too (killfile) to avoid the folks I'm most likely to get into a non-productive loop with, but as far as I know SE doesn't have that feature.

@keshlam There are folks that I usually don't make comments on their posts because even if I'm trying to be supportive and not humorous (imagine that) my comments still provoke ire or incomprehension. I just try to sneak past the sleeping dogs and move on.

Miss Understands has this (and more) on her profile page:

Emotional retardation (autism) and AvPD (psychotic-level shyness) render me literally unable to look at people or talk above a mumble. I have no idea why I'm so different online.

Does this not call for more-than-typical nuanced responses?

We should treat everyone with the same consideration that they may be neurodivergent, and provide additional accommodations only as needed/requested. It would be doing that wrong to treat someone as generically "special" (beyond specific accommodations they may need) because they're neurodivergent. But like I said elsewhere: Meta isn't really the place to air issues with specific users - there's been far too many such posts on here recently.

I have friends on the autism spectrum, and I agree that cutting them a bit more slack and being very explicit about emotional content is a good idea. And the engineering mindset is known to share some characteristics with autism, so I can understand their frustration when communication breaks down. I might even vote to reopen; as I said in comments there I think it qualifies as a teachable moment if nothing else. But I'm done with that conversation; if someone rejects modern biology there is no point talking to them about why they have trouble accepting evolution.

And for future readers, I've said what I needed to say. They can judge my answer on it's merits; it doesn't need defending.

And agreed, I shouldn't have be cited a specific user. I misread, and I was  too quick to grumble before re-reading.

That's two diagnoses (hopefully medically validated). Depending on the autism (since it is a spectrum), written communication is barely influenced, which seems to be the case judging from the last part. Therefore, additionally to the fact that we cannot accommodate every non-typical brain, I see no reason for extras. Mind, I am diagnosed with both autism and ADHD myself, which means having a serious developmental disorder in executive functioning, including the ability of social perspective taking, ie. understanding and considering appropriateness of words or other people's thoughts/feelings

@MissUnderstands: Response in other comment thread. No hatred, just miscommunication, which is fixable.

@MissUnderstands You may understand a lot more than the average Joe but there is a difference between understanding something in the sense of seeing it the way it is and understanding something in the sense of being able to integrate it in a way that it makes sense to oneself. If one takes the latter for the former without allowing for the difference it is a ticket to social problems, loneliness, and stigmatising. That has nothing to do with autism as such, though, since even if it is much more likely with this diagnosis it is definitely not a necessity.

@MissUnderstands Maybe you should read up on executive functioning and especially the social dimension on it. Helped me understand a lot about my life.

@PhilipKlöcking I already read all about autism and how brain development screws up in utero. The part that understands social interactions is absorbed by the part that does 3D visualization. I don't know if that's what happened to me. No one ever suggested that it was. But that's what happened to Einstein, according to the people who dissected his brain. == Yeah, I don't know if that's what happened to me. But it's as good explanation as any. == But knowledge is not power. You don't get extra credit for it. And it doesn't do me a god damn bit of good.

@PhilipKlöcking Read Flowers for Algernon. Scientists invent an operation that will triple your intelligence, so they test it out on a retarded guy. Everybody loved him because he was so nice. He was the janitor at a bakery where the others played mean tricks on him, but he didn't know it. He thought they were being friendly. == Post-op, he was the smartest man in the world. But it only let him see the ugliness, the evil, the unnecessary suffering. == The ultimate horror was: the operation was temporary. In the end, he was again laughing with the little kids in the playground, who loved him.
